# Adding pointers to objects to a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

I am trying to add pointers to an object to a vector in a function like this:

vector:

```
vector<struct Node*> vars;
```

function:

```
void fill_vec(){
    struct Node* temp;
    temp = new Node();
    cout << token << endl;
    temp->name = token;
    temp->value = 0;
    cout << temp << endl;
    vars.push_back(temp);
}
```

fill_vec is being called in a while loop that stops when there aren't anymore variable names.

It is adding the correct amount of nodes to the vector, but everything is pointing to the same object. Token is being parsed.

output of above:

```
a
0x9c6010
b 
0x9c6050
```

printing vector:

```
void print_vars(){
    for(int i = 0; i < vars.size(); i++){
        cout << "Name:" << vars[i]->name << endl;
        cout << "Value:" << vars[i]->value << endl;
    }
}
```

output:

```
Name:b
Value:0
Name:b
Value:0
```

*My thought was that when I allocated new memory, the address would change. When I print the address of temp each time I call the function, the address is the same*. I was printing the address wrong. The address is different for each call of the function. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Cannot make any suggestions based on the limited information provided.

Comment: `vector<struct Node*>` looks like C with Classes. Make it `vector<Node*>`.

Answer (score 0):

> My thought was that when I allocated new memory, the address would change.

It does indeed.

> When I print the address of temp each time I call the function, the address is the same.

That is because you are printing out the address of a local variable, which happens to reside at the same stack memory address each time `fill_vec()` is called.  You should be printing out the memory address of the allocated `Node` instead.

Change this line:

```
cout << &temp << endl;
```

To this:

```
cout << temp << endl;
```

Comment: Ok. After changing that the addresses printed are different, but the vector is still printing the same as above. Any further ideas?

Comment: Given the code you have shown, that is simply not possible.  The code you have not shown must be doing something to alter the content of `vars` after populating it and before printing it.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was the token. Token is a char* and I was not using strdup() on it. So every time I updated token, name was being changed in each object.